# show/hide(fade out) button for tapping

Tags: flutter

I am using `video_player`.

and this source code makes the button on Video Screen.

However I want to show up the Icon only when tapping a few seconds.

For now I put Icon on video screen, this way is correct?
Or should I do something another approach??

```
  Stack(
    children: <Widget>[

      Center(
        child: 
        _controller.value.initialized
          ? AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            )
          : Container(),
      ),
      Center(
        child:
      ButtonTheme(
        height: 100.0,
        minWidth: 200.0,
        child:RaisedButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                _controller.pause();
              } else {
                _controller.play();
              }
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
              _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
              size: 120.0,
          ),
        ),
      ), ) 
    ]
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can know when the screen is pressed using a GestureDetector onTap callback. then, when the screen is pressed you can start a timer for as long as you want the button to be visible.

use this code as an example:

```cs
// at the top of the file
import 'dart:async';

// in your widget state class
Timer t;

// in build method
Stack(
  children: [
    // your video player,
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          t?.cancel();
          t = Timer(
            Duration(seconds: 1),
            () => setState(() => t = null),
          );
        });
      },
    ),
    Center(
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          var button = // your button
          return AnimatedOpacity(
            opacity: t != null ? 1 : 0.0,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            child: t != null ? button : IgnorePointer(child: button),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you asked.
I think that you're asking how to fade the button when it is clicked.
If you want to do this you could use the `AnimatedOpacity` widget like so.

```
bool isClicked = false; // boolean that states if the button is pressed or not

Stack(
children: <Widget>[

  Center(
    child: 
    _controller.value.initialized
      ? AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        )
      : Container(),
  ),
  Center(
    child:
  ButtonTheme(
    height: 100.0,
    minWidth: 200.0,
    child:AnimatedOpacity(
      opacity: isClicked ? 0.0 : 1.0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: // how much you want the animation to be long)
      child:RaisedButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
      color: Colors.transparent,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          isClicked = true;
          if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
            _controller.pause();
          } else {
            _controller.play();
          }
        });
      },
      child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          size: 120.0,
      ),
    ),)
  ), ) 
]
),),
```

Again I don't know if I got what you asked.